# WPF TextBox Focus on constructor

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having a problem focusing on a `Control` within a `Window` in WPF.

On the constructor of the `Window` I add a `TextBox` as follows:

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.Text = input;
tb.SelectAll();
tb.Focus();
```

I also call the `Focus()` method again on the `Window` loaded event.

The problem is that sometimes the window focuses and other times it does not! This is very strange behavior and I was wondering if someone has had the same problem and might be able to give me some guidance.

-- UPDATE

I have found what is causing the problem but no solution yet. I am using WIA to scan a document, this brings up a `ProgressBar` which makes my entire application lose focus.

I have tried calling `Application.Current.MainWindow.Focus()` but this does not restore focus, any suggestions?

Comment: Do that at the end of `Window_Loaded` event, may be you are setting the focus to some other control.

Comment: Does it help to move the Focus() call to the Window.Loaded event? Edit: Habib beat me to it :)

Comment: As I mentioned in my question I do call `Focus()` again on the `Loaded` event to no avail.

Comment: @ChrisjanLodewyks, where in the loaded event ? these lines should be the last lines of the event.

Comment: @Habib, it is the only line in the loaded event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF MVVM Focus Field on Load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178449/wpf-mvvm-focus-field-on-load)

Comment: @Jehof, this `TextBox` is created in code behind as in the supplied code, can I set the `FocussedElement` from code behind?

Comment: Take a look at [FocusManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.aspx)

Comment: Find which control was focused before you call WIA, then set it back after you done with WIA.

Answer (score 0):

From memory, I think the last call on window creation is the Windows.Activated event. You could try running your focus code on that event?

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in my updated question my entire application loses focus due to another dialog being displayed, what I ended up using was:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Activate();
```

This returns focus to my application and when my `Window` with the `TextBox` is shown, `Focus` is applied to this control.

Hope it helps someone!